# Why registering for push notifications every time a user launch an app?

Tags: iphone, ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

In the Apple documentation you can find the following sentence :

> An application should register every time it launches and give its provider the current token. It calls registerForRemoteNotificationTypes: to kick off the registration process.

So when I implemented the push notification in my app I had to register the device, and I did what they said in that documentation: registering every time a user launch my app.
The token that I receive from the APNS is always the same for a given user.

My question is: why do I need to register everytime if the APNS gives me always the same token?

I read somewhere than a token can change if a user swipe his iPhone or the app. Is it the only case?

Thank you !

Answer (score 34, accepted):

> The token that I receive from the APNS is always the same for a given user.

Except it isn't, basically because there's nothing you can hang onto as being "a user" in the iPhone setup. The device token is always the same for each app for each **device**. So different apps on the same device get different tokens. The same app on two different devices gets two different tokens.

The crucial thing to note, and this is mentioned in the APNS guide, is that a user may back up their apps, settings, everything. Then they can drop their phone down the toilet. When they get their replacement phone, they can take their backup and restore it onto their new phone. Bingo - same app, same user, different device, **and different token**.

As far as your app is concerned, nothing has changed since the last time it ran - it doesn't know that it's actually running on a different device now. The only way it knows is because it asks for the 'current' device token, and hey presto it's a different token to last time.

You can choose to cache the token and check it against the token you just received (e.g. save it in your NSUserDefaults) - that way you don't have to communicate it back to the server unless it has changed since the last run, but you absolutely do have to check, otherwise your users will come complaining that they don't get push notifications any more since they replaced their phone.

Comment: If you "check it against the token you just received", then why not just use the new token (even if it's the same), you already made the call and already received the new token..

Comment: I think you misunderstand what "using" means in this context. The **app** is checking the token it just got back from the APNS call against something stored in the preferences locally. That's cheap, and doesn't involve any network access or contacting your server. As far as the server is concerned nothing has changed so it doesn't need to know. If the token has changed, then the server absolutely **does** need to know, because it's going to need to be sending push notifications using a different token next time..

Comment: @MrCranky but then how do I know that the token has changed. The only way to get device token I know is to call `registerForRemoteNotifications` and that call makes a request to server [and syncs stuffs (I suppose)].

Comment: `registerForRemoteNotifications` talks to the push notification service on the device, not your own server. That doesn't have to involve network access. You can test this by putting your phone into airplane mode before starting your app. If I recall correctly, you'll still get a response with a token, because at some point in the past the device will have negotiated with Apple's server what its token is, and that token doesn't change just because you're currently offline. You should be sending the new token to your server if you detect one, retrying periodically if you can't straight away.