# iOS 8 Remote notifications - When should I call registerForRemoteNotifications()?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, apple-push-notifications

As the apple's official info page about push notification states:

"Device tokens can change, so your app needs to reregister **every time it is launched**."

I trying to understand what they meant by "every time it is launched".
Does it mean I have to call it in the AppDelegate, in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions() like so:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

    application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
    return true
}
```

Putting this code here will cause it to execute every time the user opens the app, which could be many times a minute if the user is multi tasking between apps (going back and forth between them).

And since calling the registration method invokes an HTTP request to APNS, there is a risk of getting temporary ban.

Are those observations are correct, or I can put the register method like so without any fear?

(I am using xcode 6.2 with Swift)

Comment: Yes, you should register in that method.  Even if the user is switching back and forth between your app and another the chances are your app will stay in memory and simply move to the suspended state rather than actually exiting

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` is not called every time the user switches to your app, as often your app is still running. What you're describing sounds more like `applicationDidBecomeActive`.

Add some `NSLog`s to both methods to convince yourself that `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` is the right place to call `.registerForRemoteNotifications`.

Comment: So as Apple suggest, device tokens can change at any time so as well as calling registerForRemoteNotification in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions(), it is also sensible to put it in applicationDidBecomeActive().

Comment: Interesting - I see the "at any time" mentioned here: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/HandlingRemoteNotifications.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH6-SW3  but it also says "When the device token changes, the user must launch your app once before remote notifications can once again be delivered to that device." so why not use only `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`?

Comment: Good point although when I saw that, I read its  meaning "this does not happen in the background" and happens only when launching the app (either from background or from terminated). Wish Apple would be a bit clearer in their docs and use of words.

Answer (score 5):

## A 2021 update

In the [latest apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplication/1623078-registerforremotenotifications), there is no such information about when/ where you should call it. I assume they have simplified the API.

From the `application(_:didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:)` [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1622958-application):

> Typically, this method is called only after you call the registerForRemoteNotifications() method of UIApplication, **but UIKit might call it in other rare circumstances**. For example, UIKit calls the method when the user launches an app **after having restored a device from data that is not the device’s backup data**. In this exceptional case, the app won’t know the new device’s token until the user launches it.

Using a different document (potentially outdated) from Apple, [Configuring Remote Notification Support](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/HandlingRemoteNotifications.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH6-SW3),

> If the device token changes while your app is running, the app object calls the `application:didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:` delegate method again to notify you of the change

So it seems like it's **not** your responsibility to call it **frequently** (e.g. at launch, between app switches) anymore. Just call it once when you want need a `deviceToken`, and your `application:didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken` will be called when it gets renewed. I've tested that I can call the `registerForRemoteNotifications` outside of `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` and `willFinishLaunchingWithOptions`, it worked fine. It's harder to test that Apple will call `application:didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken`.

---

Because Apple docs have been changing many times in the past, I'm reproducing the discussion section below from August 2021:

> ### Discussion
>
> Call this method to initiate the registration process with Apple Push Notification service. If registration succeeds, the
> app calls your app delegate object’s
> application:didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken: method
> and passes it a device token. You should pass this token along to the
> server you use to generate remote notifications for the device. If
> registration fails, the app calls its app delegate’s
> application:didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError: method
> instead.
>
> If you want your app’s remote notifications to display alerts, play
> sounds, or perform other user-facing actions, you must request
> authorization to do so using the
> requestAuthorizationWithOptions:completionHandler: method of
> UNUserNotificationCenter. If you do not request and receive
> authorization for your app's interactions, the system delivers all
> remote notifications to your app silently.

Answer (score 4):

Answering to your exact question:-
you can put the register method in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions without any fear. It is recommended by apple itself.

Case 1:-
If in your plist "Application does not run in background" is set to NO, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions will not be called every time the app opens.
It will be called if the app launches completely from a terminated state.
Only applicationDidBecomeActive will be called whenever the app launches from background state. No need to put register method in applicationDidBecomeActive.

Case 2:-
And if in your plist "Application does not run in background" is set to YES, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions will be called every time the app opens. you can put the register method in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions without any fear.

Comment: Thank you! didn't know about "Application does not run in background"

Comment: I would not recommend this approach, you'll be forcing your app to get cold started every single time it's opened, which is going to have a significant performance impact!

Answer (score 4):

According to the [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/HandlingRemoteNotifications.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH6-SW1) for `registerForRemoteNotifications()`,

> After successful APNs registration, the app object contacts APNs only when the device token has changed; otherwise, calling the registerForRemoteNotifications method results in a call to the application:didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken: method which returns the existing token quickly.

Calling the registration method does not invoke an HTTP request to APNS if it is not necessary.

This [StackOverflow Comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4117395/why-registering-for-push-notifications-every-time-a-user-launch-an-app#comment52510803_4166801) confirms this empirically:

> You can test this by putting your phone into airplane mode before starting your app. If I recall correctly, you'll still get a response with a token, because at some point in the past the device will have negotiated with Apple's server what its token is, and that token doesn't change just because you're currently offline.