# How to switch push notification providers without re-prompting to enable push notifications?

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, remote-notifications

There are many third party push notification providers like Appboy (Braze), Localytics, Urban Airship, etc. Our app is in production using "Provider A" but we are switching to "Provider B." Fresh installations get push notifications, but upgrade installations do not. Upon inspection it looks like `didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken` isn't called. How can push be enabled without having to re-prompt the user?

Answer (score 1):

It is enough to call `registerForRemoteNotifications` in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`. It will trigger `didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken` or `didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError` callback if they've opted-in. The best part is that the callbacks are triggered if they opt-in sometime in the future (Assuming they've been prompted in-app at least once via `registerUserNotificationSettings`).

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    //...
        UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()
    //...
}
```

See:
[iOS 8 Remote notifications - When should I call registerForRemoteNotifications()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29456954/ios-8-remote-notifications-when-should-i-call-registerforremotenotifications)

Comment: what do you mean by `didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken` is successfully called?

Comment: AFAIK `registerForRemoteNotifications` never prompts the user. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42275060/what-is-difference-between-remote-notification-and-silent-notification-in-ios/42302369#42302369) and look for "Registering does NOT require user permission"